yarn install command not working properly
Yarn installation for react native project command yarn install not working
yarn start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dynamicmethods/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.4.cjs'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:893:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.14.0


This seems due to an issue with the Yarn installation or configuration.
you trying to use yarn-3.6.4.cjs
try:
npm install --global yarn
yarn set version 3.6.4


first command working properly but when i run second command it display same error

you can try delete ALL the global yarn configuration files.
open terminal: rm -f ~/.yarn*.
then Run yarn set version stable or your specific version
and run yarn install again
